# Rails migration with unique index, null: false, default: ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `subdomain` column in my `project` table. I allow premium users to update the subdomain and free users cannot update it. I also want unique subdomains so that there is no conflict. Currently, I have a setup like this:

#### Project migration

```rb
create_table :projects, id: uuid do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false, default: ""
  t.string :subdomain, null: false, default: ""
end

add_index :projects, :subdomain, unique: true
```

#### project.rb (model)

```rb
validates :subdomain, length: { maximum: 63 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, allow_blank: true }
```

The problem is if the free user updates the project `table`'s `name` attribute, the `subdomain` is passed as an empty string as `param`, and with my current setup, it is not possible for another free user to update the `project` table as the user would also pass in an empty string for the `subdomain` column and would result in an error.

Currently, I am fixing this bug by overwriting the `subdomain=` method, removing the `null: false`, and removing the `default: ""` from the `subdomain` column

```rb
def subdomain=(value)
  default_value = value.blank? ? nil : value
  super(default_value)
end
```

I know I can also overwrite the `param` hash, but I want to know if there are any other solutions to this. I am willing to change my migration as well.

Comment: You should add a unique constraint for name AND subdomain combined.

Comment: Why would I add a unique constraint for `name`? I do not want a unique `name` column.

Comment: You allow the name of the project to be same ? Is there a possibility that project’s name and subdomain of two different users will be same ?

Comment: Subdomain has to be unique while project name can be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- Add nullable `subdomain` field with unique index; `null: true`
- Add:

```rb
   validates :subdomain, length: { maximum: 63 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: f 
 alse }, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been trying.

Comment: @AbeidAhmed you can try to use `before_save` method, which will check
`subdomain = subdomain.present? ? subdomain : nil `

Comment: Will consider your solution.